# Does AllowDBNull reflect what's really going on the database?

Tags: vb.net, oracle

I'm working on binding a `GridControl` to a Database using VB.NET.

While inserting data in the `gridcontrol`, I would like to validate what has been inserted, mainly related to null values which may not be allowed : If a Column in the database doesn't accept null values, raise exception if the value in the grid control is null.

I'm trying to make it dynamically so I use `AllowDBNull` property from the `DataTable` to check whether the null value is allowed or not but it seems like it's not reflecting what's in the database. Some columns doesn't allow null value in the Database but in the VB.NET side, `AllowDBNull` is marked true.

I'm using a workaround which is running an Oracle query to get the information about the columns I'm interested in but it's a pretty heavy workaround.

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME, NULLABLE FROM ALL_TAB_COLUMNS WHERE OWNER = 'TABLEOWNER' AND TABLE_NAME = 'TABLENAME';
```

Here is a preview of what I get https://www.dropbox.com/s/vxzqqjhoheyqm13/2013-10-27%2016h57_50.mp4

Is `AllowDBNull` the right property I should look at ?

Thank you.

Comment: Within the scope of a form, you'd generally know which columns are allowed to be empty and which ones are not. Accessing the schema for this information is an overhead. Anyway, the AllowDBNull is supposed to be automatically set when you fill the table usign _adapter.Fill.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is to create a form to insert data in any table of the database. So I don't know really in advance which column can be empty or not. Is there any reason that AllowDBNull is different from the database ?

Comment: I think it may have to do with the way you fill the database. If you use Fill method it should be OK, if you use Reader then you have to take care of that manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think we need to call FillSchema method explicitly to reflect the correct setting. From:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a64ba847-97b5-44fe-9b63-6fdfd75fbbe4/why-the-property-allowdbnull-of-the-datacolumn-is-always-true